# convert files in good sequence

Tags: bash, converters, glob

I am trying to convert some PNG files into one GIF file.  I used the following line of code to do that:

```
convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 boxed*.png movie2.gif
```

where the `boxed*.png` are the input PNG files:

- boxed0.png
- boxed1.png
- ...
- boxed11.png
- boxed12.png
- ...
- boxed20.png
- boxed21.png
- ...

and so on.

The problem is that the correct order is not preserved. During the convert process the files are re-ordered as follows:

- boxed1.png
- boxed11.png
- boxed12.png
- ....
- boxed2.png
- boxed21.png
- ...
- boxed3.png
- boxed31.png
- ...

and so on.

How can I choose the correct order for the files inside the convert command? Or maybe I need to re-define them in another way?

Comment: See [List files sorted numerically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the number of files, you can use brace expansion:

```
convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 boxed{1..100}.png movie2.gif
```

Unlike globs, brace expansion results aren't sorted lexicographically.

Comment: I thought the files starts at `boxed0`?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
ls -v boxed*.png | convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 - movie2.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
ls box* | sort -n -t 'd' -k 2
```

you will get the output in the order you want I believe.  Do you have to pass in the files all at once or could you pipe them individually through a bash for loop?

Comment: `ls -v boxed*.png` should do the job.

Comment: Yep.  Forgot about that - much more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use version sort:

```
seq --format='boxed%.0f.png' 0 10 | shuf | sort -V
```

Output:

```
boxed0.png
boxed1.png
boxed2.png
boxed3.png
boxed4.png
boxed5.png
boxed6.png
boxed7.png
boxed8.png
boxed9.png
boxed10.png
```

Command:

```
convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 $(printf '%s\n' boxed*.png | sort -V) movie2.gif
```

Or perhaps the little more proper way:

```
readarray -t FILES < <(printf '%s\n' boxed*.png | sort -V)
[[ ${#FILES[@]} -gt 0 ]] && convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 "${FILES[@]}" movie2.gif
```

Answer (score 1):

[Globbing behavior](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs#customization) can be influenced and with a little trick you get filenames from boxed0.png to boxed99.png in correct order:

```
shopt -s nullglob    # remove patterns which not match

convert -quality 100 -delay 40 -loop 1 boxed[0-9].png boxed[0-9][0-9].png movie2.gif
```